# On the existence of a bounded linear functional

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. By the Riesz Representation Theorem, we have that any bounded linear $\psi \in \mathcal{H}^{*}$ is of the form $\psi(h) = \langle h, g \rangle$ for some $g \in \mathcal{H}$. I need to determine $g$ such that $\|\psi\| = 1$ and $\psi(h) = \|h\|$. I tried replacing $g = \displaystyle \frac{h}{\|h\|}$ but not luck. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did good.

If $\phi=(\cdot,g)$ then $\|\phi\|=\|g\|$, i.e. Riesz representation is an isometric isomorphism. Indeed, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $\|\phi\|\leq\|g\|$. And $\phi(g)=\|g\|^2$ so $\phi(g/\|g\|)=\|g\|$ hence $\|\phi\|\geq  \|g\|$.

Now you see that $g=\frac{h}{\|h\|}$ yields $\|\phi\|=\|g\|=1$ and $\phi(h)=(h,g)=\|h\|^2/\|h\|=\|h\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Stefan You're welcome. Glad it helped.